# IntelliJ Idea Completion Error

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea

I am new to Idea IDE. After installed it for a few days, I was fascinated with its outstanding features.

However, while I was actually writing code yesterday. I discovered that when the auto completion popped out, it showed nothing about the method of the object , merely some basic template say sync() var() ..... etc.

I have tried to setup the environment (Check the power save ...etc), but those previous solution seems to be for those whose auto-completion is turned off . Is there a way to fix it ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have create your project, you might not have marked it as a Java project and provide a SDK.
You can check it in File -> Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK.
If not, you can download the JDK on the Oracle site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
You can also try to write a

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("It works !");
}
```

and write click on the "main" word. You should have a "Run 'Main'" option.

Comment: I have found the solution to this , while I was edit the project in a larger scale (included the root directory). It seems to not offer me the completion. However, while I was edit it in a one project only scale. It offered me the completion. Anyway, still grateful concerning your advice. Great Thanks!